# Correct placement of the buttons in relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have designed the following layout http://i61.tinypic.com/33w1oy1.jpg

But it looks like this in any device: http://i60.tinypic.com/zvbxiu.png

Why there is a gap between the inquiry and training buttons.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/bExit"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/Exit" />

    <Button style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/bInquiry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bContactus   "
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/buttonInquiry" />

    <Button style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:id="@+id/bContactus "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bExit"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/buttonContactUs"
        android:background="#f7f0db" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bServices"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/buttonServices" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bTraining"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bServices"
        android:text="@string/buttonTraining"
        android:background="#f7f0db" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"

        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bAboutUs"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fblike"
        android:src="@drawable/dgtklogo554a527" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAboutUs"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#f7f0db"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bServices"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/buttonAbtus" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please suggest what changes to do with the buttons to avoid such a situation.

Comment: Just as a note, you don't need android:layout_width="match_parent" and the attributes `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`as a width of match_parent will already set the left and right to align with the parents left and right sides.

Comment: Your problem is caused by your android:layout_above="@+id/xxxxx" and android:layout_below="@+id/xxxxx" setting. you must use a logic  order.
in all cases, the answer of @piyush is the best way to do your view

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **RelativeLayout** use **LinearLayout** and set its **orientation** property vertical `android:orientation="vertical"` then **add item one by one** you will achieve your layout.This will be **memory efficient and fast compared** to RelativeLayout as RelativeLayout depends on various relation between view and make view slow.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case that you decide to stick with `RelativeLayout`, the issue is that you have two groups of unrelated controls. Right now the relationship is the following:

```
bExit <- bContactus <- bInquiry

bServices <- bTraining
 ^
 |
bAboutUs <- imageView1
```

Instead it should be like this:

```
bExit <- bContactus <- bInquiry <- bTraining <- bServices <- bAboutUs <- imageView1
```